# How does this discouraging Python one-liner that displays the mandlebrot set work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, one-liner

Could you please explain how it works.

In particular: where do `a`,`c`,`n`,`s`,`z` come from?
And how to convert this to regular functions and their calls?

```
x=10
y=5
abs( (lambda a: lambda z, c, n: a(a, z, c, n)) (lambda s, z, c, n: z if n == 0 else s(s, z*z+c, c, n-1)) (0, 0.02*x+0.05j*y, 10) )
```

It was even longer, but I figured out the rest of it.

```
print('\n'.join([''.join(['*'if abs((lambda a: lambda z, c, n: a(a, z, c, n))(lambda s, z, c, n: z if n == 0 else s(s, z*z+c, c, n-1))(0, 0.02*x+0.05j*y, 40)) < 2 else ' ' for x in range(-80, 20)]) for y in range(-20, 20)]))
```

This monster expression outputs a pseudo-graphic Mandelbrot fractal to the console.

Comment: not so production level code, hard to handle, it is nested lambda function calls

Comment: The variables a, c,... are parameters of the lambda functions. They can have nearly arbitrary names instead.

Comment: Generally `f = lambda <parameters>: <expression>` can be written as `def f(<parameters>): return <expression>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function  `(lambda a: lambda z, c, n: a(a, z, c, n))` can be rewritten as

```
def apply_function_to_itself(funk):
    def inner(arg1, arg2, arg3):
        funk(funk, arg1, arg2, arg3)
        
    return inner
```

This is a functional thing that calls a function with itself as the first argument. This is necessary for recursion in functional languages but in python there is usually a better way.

This function `(lambda s, z, c, n: z if n == 0 else s(s, z*z+c, c, n-1))` can be rewritten as this:

```py
def transform_n_times(funk, value, c, n):
    if n==0:
        return arg1
    else:
        return funk(funk, value * value + constant, constant, n-1)
```

We know from the previous function that `funk === call_if_n_is_not_0`, so this
is a recursive function that will apply a operation `n` times before stopping.

So basically combined we can rewrite it like this:

```
def transform_n_times(value, constant, n):
    for i in range(n):
        value arg1 * arg1 + arg2
    return value
```

Much simpler.

## Understanding the entire program

The entire code could be written like this:

```
def apply_function_to_itself(funk):
    def inner(arg1, arg2, arg3):
        funk(funk, arg1, arg2, arg3)
        
    return inner

def transform_n_times(funk, value, constant, n):
    if n==0:
        return arg1
    else:
        return funk(funk, value * value + constant, constant, n-1)

abs(apply_function_to_itself(call_if_n_is_not_0)(0, 0.02*x+0.05j*y, 10))
```

Or like this. We can get rid of the `apply_function_to_itself` entirely but keep the recursion like this:

```py
def transform_n_times(value, constant, n):
    if n==0:
        return arg1
    else:
        return transform_n_times(funk, value * value + constant, constant, n-1)

abs(transform_n_times(0, 0.02*x+0.05j*y, 10))
```

Or we can delete the recursion entirely and just use a loop:

```
constant = 0.02*x+0.05j*y
value = 0
n = 10
for i in range(n):
    a1 = value * value + constant
abs(value)
```

The basic equation behind the mandlebrot set is `f(x) = x^2+c` which matches this.

Comment: I think it is worth to mention that ` z*z+c` is the basic iteration of the Mandelbrot set: if it stays bounded (`< 2` in the comprehension that OP mentioned) the point is part of the set, thus an `*`, otherwise it is not.